# Как сравнивается TimeSpan с int

Tags: c#, дата

у меня есть такой код, где я проверяю интрервалы, и сравниваю TimeSpan со значением типа int.
Хочетлось узнать, как они сравниваются между собой, и корректно ли делать такое сравнение?
YearInteval имеет тип int.

```
          DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
          for (int i = 0; i < invent.Count; i++)
          {

              if (dateService[i] == null)
              {
                  continue;
              }
              else
              {
                  DateTime date = (DateTime)dateService[i];
                  TimeSpan interval = now.Subtract(date);

                  if (invent.Select(x => x.Servicedate).ToList() == null)
                  {
                      continue;
                  }
                  else if (interval.TotalDays > YearInteval)
                  {
                     //какая то логика
                  }
              }
```

Comment: Вы не сравниваете `TimeSpan` с `int`, вы сравниваете значение свойства `TimeSpan.TotalDays`, имеющего тип `double`, с `int`. Сравнение дробных и целых чисел - отдельная тема (например, равен ли 1 целый день и 1.00000000001 дня? или 0.999999999999 дня? стоит ли допускать какую-то незначительную погрещность?), но тут решение уже вам принимать, исходя из ваших потребностей.

Comment: @aa_talanin точно, спасибо